# How to get data (objects) besides list from paging 3 in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, paging

So I got an API Response like this:

```
{
  "name": "Ranpo X",
  "id": "ranpo-x",
  "total": 4419,
  "pagination": {
    "totalItems": 4419,
    "pageSize": 10,
    "startPage": 1,
  },
  "items": [
    ...
  ]
```

How can I get value in "name" or "id" field, since `LoadResult.Page()`'s "data" parameter only accepts `List<Value>`?

How can I get other values besides the list and pass them into my Repository?